# Error in React versions in nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, meteor, module, vulcan

i has installed a version of Vulcan framework and React packages make a error with the package react-datetime. He no find module create-react-class
and produce this error (sugestions):

```
Error: Cannot find module 'create-react-class'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/marcioantoniorezende/Documents/devs/Vulcan/node_modules/react-datetime/DateTime.js:5:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17) Exited with code: 1 Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.

Warning: Accessing PropTypes via the main React package is deprecated,
and will be removed in  React v16.0. Use the latest available v15.*
prop-types package from npm instead. For info on usage, compatibility,
migration and more


Warning: Accessing createClass via the main React package is
deprecated, and will be removed in React v16.0. Use a plain JavaScript
class instead. If you're not yet ready to migrate, create-react-class
v15.* is available on npm as a temporary, drop-in replacement.
```

Comment: show me result of `npm list`

Comment: Solved:
sudo npm install -g create-react-class

Comment: another solution, in Vulcan package:
$ cd node_modules/react-datetime
$ npm install create-react-class